# Why is my module not showing in the add-ons list?

Tags: ee2, module

I am building a simple little module, based on this tutorial;

http://ee-recipes.com/articles/details/our-first-module-part-2-setting-up-the-file-structure

I have called my module 'DownloadLogs'
I have created the upd.downloadlogs.php, mcp.downloadlogs.php and mod.downloadlogs.php files, and also a lang.downloadlogs.php file.

I have put them all in /system/expressionengine/third_party/downloadlogs and uploaded to my server. But I can't see them in the list of installable add-ons. I have also cleared all of the caches and logged out and in again as superadmin.

Have I missed anything? What does EE require to pick up my code as an available module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good on you for writing your first plugin.
Use this as a starting point for your plugins, quick, easy and avoids missing something.
[pkg.io](http://pkg.io/)
Create it, download, unzip and upload to third party folder, just like any other add on. Once you can 'see' it in the plugin/module list you're all set to add your code.

Comment: Wow, I love it. It worked, so now I will dissect the one pkg.io created and see what was missing form mine!

Comment: Also, find another plugin that has similar functionaily to what you want to do and study the code. That recipe walk through is a great starting point. Ive referred to it myself a few times in the last 12 mths.

Comment: And if you are just starting template development, consider this approach. Ive just finished a complete rebuild of 50+ templates using this partials approach + stash. 100 times better. http://eeinsider.com/articles/template-partials-using-stash